# How to add onClick event to an a tag with class

Tags: jquery, append

Here's what I have on a page

```
<a class="download-link" href="http://www.test.com/pages-">Pages 1</a>
```

Below is the Result I want to achieve with jQuery.

```
<a class="download-link" href="http://www.test.com/pages-1.asp" onclick="_sz.push(['event', 'PDF', 'download', ('report') ])">Pages 1</a>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">/
$('.download-link').each(function(){
    this.href += '-1.asp';
    this.attr('onclick', '_sz.push(['event', 'PDF', 'download-request', ('report') ])');
})
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need `onclick`?, Just use `$('.download-link').click(function(){
    _sz.push(['event', 'PDF', 'download-request', ('nhs-companies-an-enterprising-approach-to-health') ]);
})`

Comment: In your jQuery-Selector you should use the correct class: `$('.download-link')`

Comment: @Satpal I need it for analytics reasons for tracking event.

Comment: Using JS to add an attribute which calls JS is a little redundant. Add an unobtrusive event handler directly to the element as @Satpal suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

```
$('.download-link').bind('click', function (event) {
    _sz.push(['event', 'PDF', 'download', ('report')])
});
```

I hope. It helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `prop` insted of `attr` in jquery

```
//before
this.attr('onclick', '_sz.push(...)');

//after
this.prop('onclick', '_sz.push(...)');
```